# Adding information to xAxis - r shiny

Tags: r, highcharts, axis-labels

I have an issue with some plots in Rshiny. I would like to add some information to the xAxis. This post was edited because I almost found a solution, but if you want the original script, I can provide it.

Here is a reproductible example :

```
 library("shiny")
library("highcharter")

data(citytemp)

ui <- fluidPage(
    h1("Highcharter EXAMPLE"),
    fluidRow(
        column(width = 8,
               highchartOutput("hcontainer",height = "500px")
        ),
        selectInput("option", label = "",  width = "100%",
                    choices = c("Tokyo", "NY"))
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    data <- citytemp[,c("month","tokyo","new_york")]
    data = data[data$month%in%c("Dec","Jan","Feb","Mar"),]
    choose_Option <- reactive({
        sort_option <- input$option
        if(sort_option=="Tokyo"){
            data = data[order(data$tokyo),]
        }
        else{
            data = data[order(data$new_york),]
        }
        return(data)
    })
    output$hcontainer <- renderHighchart({
        data = choose_Option()
        data = data[1:3,] 


        chart <-  highchart() %>% 
            hc_chart(type = "bar") %>% 
            hc_title(text = "Monthly Average Temperature for main cities") %>% 
            hc_subtitle(text = "Source: WorldClimate.com") %>% 
            hc_xAxis(categories = data$month ,                    
                     labels=list(
                         formatter=JS("function () {
                             return 'Tokyo' + '<br>' +  this.categories  +'         '  + '<br>'+'NY' + '</br>';
                         }"))) %>% 
            hc_yAxis(title = list(text = "Temperature (C)")) 

        hc <- chart %>% hc_add_series(yAxis=0,name="Tokyo",data = data$tokyo,colorByPoint=TRUE )
        hc <- hc %>% hc_add_series(yAxis=0,name="NY",data = data$new_york,colorByPoint=TRUE )    



        return(hc)
    })
} 

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Here is an illustration of what I would like to have:

[image]

The solution is almost working but I face two problems:
 1) how can I ask R to get the category name ? I think that this.category is not working ... and 2) why is the long whitespace not taken into account ?

Let me know if you need any clarification.
Thank you very much, 
Best, Madzia

Comment: Could post an image of an expected chart? You should be able to change format of axis labels or use dataLabels (point labels). Exemplary data might be helpful too.

Comment: Hello Kacper, thank you for your message - I just edited the post, can you view the picture ?

Comment: Will this be close enough? http://jsfiddle.net/7kk1ku9v/2/ It uses dataLabels with format to show series name instead of default y values.

Comment: Actually I already have data labels, but have deleted them for simplifying purposes. But I can maybe overlap two graphs ...

Comment: Do you have any problems with Highcharts? How can I help?

Comment: Hi Kacper, I just edited my post because I found an intermediate solution. Maybe you can help me on this ? It is mainly about labels' formatting

Answer (score 0):

1) You could use `this.key` to get a current category (so Feb, Jan or Mar in case of your images and a demo below)

2) Extra white spaces are ignored - you could place them in a `<span>` with `white-space:pre;` style.

Additionally, regarding labels position in the "wanted" image, you could set options like:

```
align: 'left',
inside: true,
x: -65
```

...for dataLabels to have them on left side of each bar if there is enough space  (if not - on right side).

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7kk1ku9v/3/